# How to test my app roaming settings

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, settings, winjs

I am creating a windows 8 app. I want to save some settings as roaming. My understanding is that every app get per app and per user roaming settings on the azure cloud but it only happen once you app is published to store. While developing my app, if I don’t have any roaming account what’s the best way to test m y app to ensure roaming settings to be working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for your app to be published to use roaming settings. I was able to do so while developing my application.

What you need:

- Two Windows 8 Devices (not windows Phone)
- The same Microsoft login on each device (it's best to use the account linked to your Windows Store Developer account). This used to be known as a "Live" login, but I'm not sure what the latest terminology is.
- Your application installed on both devices, using the Microsoft login

Data should be synced, as long as your application properly reads/ writes from the roaming settings/ folder.

Although it doesn't specifically discuss requirements, you may want to take a look at the [Roaming Data Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx). There is helpful information there on the limitations (data size, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am confused when you say app installed on both devices using same Microsoft login. Like I said I am not installing app, I am running through VS to debug the app. Also where I need to login to Microsoft site during all this?

Comment: @PaulSnow - Maybe we need to take a step back. Roaming data is user data (settings) that are sync'd between multiple devices. For example, you might save the user's sort order on your app's home screen on device 1. When the user opens your app on device 2, then the sort order is the same as on device 1. In order for syncing to work, the user must be logging into each device with the same Microsoft account. Perhaps I misread your intention - I assumed you wanted to test that the roaming settings are synced across devices.

Comment: @PaulSnow - From this link: [Info on Windows 8 Microsoft Accounts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/microsoft-account). *Your Microsoft account is your key to free online storage, mobile entertainment, apps in the Windows Store, and connecting your devices and accounts seamlessly. The first step is to sign in to your PC with your Microsoft account.*